# Как очистить все поле ввода (Text) с помощью кнопки меню?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Были варианты

```
def delete_all(self):
    self.text.delete(0, 'end')
```

или

```
def delete_all(self):
    text.delete(1.0, 'End')
```

и еще много вариантов...

Но ни один вариант не сработал. Что делать?
Вот весь код:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Ocno")
root.geometry("1000x600")

def delete_all():
    text.delete(1.0, 'END')

text = Text(root, height = 340, width = 500)
text.grid(row=2, column=0)

main_menu = Menu()
delete_menu=Menu()
delete_menu.add_command(label="Delete all", command=delete_all)

main_menu.add_cascade(label="Delete all", menu=delete_menu)

root.config(menu=main_menu)
 
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: А разве это не одно и тоже? И там и там ввод
Как очистить все поле ввода (entry) с помощью кнопки меню - определитесь entry или text? В заголовке одно, в коде другое. Это разные объекты, очистка работать будет по разному. – insolor

Comment: Нет, ну...



Не влезло  - потому что не нужно пытаться целиком воткнуть условие в заголовок. В заголовке должна быть только суть вопроса, а сам вопрос в теле. – insolor 42 минуты назад

Comment: `А разве это не одно и тоже?` - нет, класс Text и класс Entry работают совершенно по-разному. Поэтому уточните, что конкретно вам нужно.

Comment: Я оставил только один вопрос и проголосовал за переоткрытие. Остальные вопросы нужно задать отдельно.

Answer (score 2):

Для вашего случая рабочие варианты такие:

```
text.delete(1.0, END)
```

или

```
text.delete(1.0, 'end')
```

При варианте импорта `import tkinter as tk` вместо `END` нужно использовать `tk.END`.

У вас первый вариант не рабочий, потому что `self` есть только в методах классов (у вас `delete_all` - просто функция, и нет переменных с именем `self`), и индекс начала в текстовом поле `Text` не 0, а 1.0. Во втором случае нужно было написать `'end'` вместо `'End'`, и все бы заработало.

Comment: Спасибо! Но ваш вариант тоже не работает(

Comment: @CATpython, я прямо засомневался и решил перепроверить на всякий случай. В итоге, у меня оба варианта работают. Я просто скопировал код из вопроса и поменял строку с удалением на строку из ответа.

Answer (score 0):

1. Индекс делается по строке и символу в ней: `text.delete(1.0, tk.END)`
2. ```
   import tkinter as tk
   root = tk.Tk()
   def change_font():
       lab.config(font = (e.get(), 11))
   lab = tk.Label(root, text = 'text label')
   lab.pack()
   tk.Button(root, text = 'сменить шрифт', command = change_font).pack()
   e = tk.Entry(root)
   e.pack()
   root.mainloop()
   ```
3. `ans = myentry.get()`

Comment: 1. Не получилось(. Уже был такой вариант.
2. Я имею в виду немного другое! То есть я пишу в поле ввода и уже тогда меняю шрифт. А у Вас готовый текст!
3. Получилось так: 
Поле ввода: ans = tk.Entry(window, validate='key', validatecommand=vcmd)
Перемещаем значение: a=ans.get()
И когда нажимаю кнопку, такая ошибка: TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
Exception in Tkinter callback.


Все равно спасибо!

Comment: `e = tk.Entry(window) ;e.pack() ;e.get()` Может ошибка в `validate='key', validatecommand=vcmd`

Comment: Не знаю. Но думаю, что ошибка в ```a=copy.copy(ans)```, наверно как-то по-другому копируется.